# No real solution for 3 coupled equations, but then how "close" can one get?

Tags: equation-solving

I have three equations involving $x$, $y$, and $z$ that I would like to find a unique solution to, in the Reals.

`NSolve` does not find anything:

```
NSolve[{Sqrt[1 / (x^4)] == Sqrt[1 /((y^3) z )], 
  Sqrt[1 / (x^4)] == Sqrt[(1/x^4 + 1 /( y z^3))], 
  Sqrt[1 /( (y^3) z )] == Sqrt[(1 /x^4 + 1 /(y z^3))]}, {x, y, 
  z}, Reals]
```

which seems confirmed by a CountourPlot3D which shows no intersection:

```
ContourPlot3D[{Sqrt[1 / (x^4)] == Sqrt[1 /((y^3) z )], 
  Sqrt[1 / (x^4)] == Sqrt[(1/x^4 + 1 /( y z^3))], 
  Sqrt[1 /( (y^3) z )] == Sqrt[(1 /x^4 + 1 /(y z^3))]}, {x, 0, 
  100}, {y, 0, 100}, {z, 0, 100}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

**Question**: is there a way to find "approximate" solutions, specifying an accuracy range within which a solution could be? I.e. a particular (x,y,z) combo obviously doesn't give 0 to one of my equations, but maybe gives 0.1 and that'd be good enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Reformulate as a minimization problem

```
expr = Subtract @@@ {Sqrt[1/(x^4)] == Sqrt[1/((y^3) z)], 
   Sqrt[1/(x^4)] == Sqrt[(1/x^4 + 1/(y z^3))], 
   Sqrt[1/((y^3) z)] == Sqrt[(1/x^4 + 1/(y z^3))]}

(* {Sqrt[1/x^4] - Sqrt[1/(y^3 z)], 
 Sqrt[1/x^4] - Sqrt[1/x^4 + 1/(y z^3)], -Sqrt[1/x^4 + 1/(y z^3)] + Sqrt[1/(
  y^3 z)]} *)
```

Minimizing the sum of the squares

```
{min, arg} = 
 NMinimize[Join[{Total[expr^2]}, Thread[0 <= {x, y, z} <= 100]], {x, y, z},
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution",
  WorkingPrecision -> 17]

(* {1.2736005375588001*10^-9, {x -> 44.219798564468166, y -> 32.928582883862153, 
  z -> 99.999999784859630}} *)

expr /. arg

(* {-0.0000178183282646516, -0.0000288761531935047, -0.0000110578249288531} *)
```

Comment: Note that increasing the allowed range of `x,y,z` seems to reliably yield a solution of the form $x \approx 0.4 z, y \approx 0.3 z$, and $z$ maxed out within the allowed range.  Doing so also decreases the value of `min`.  There's probably a way to prove this analytically, but I don't see it immediately.